# Why do HashMap::get and HashMap::entry take different types of key?

Tags: generics, rust, hashmap

The signature of `HashMap::entry` is:

```
pub fn entry(&mut self, key: K) -> Entry<'_, K, V>
```

OK, looks good. I want to take an entry from the HashMap whose key is `K`, so of course I need to give it a `K`.

However, the signature of `HashMap:get` is:

```
pub fn get<Q>(&self, k: &Q) -> Option<&V>
where
    K: Borrow<Q>,
    Q: Hash + Eq + ?Sized,
```

Now I'm utterly confused. What's with this complicated constraint? Why isn't it just `K` or `&K`?

Comment: quoting docs: "The key may be any borrowed form of the map’s key type". This allows you to call `get(&str)` on a `HashMap<String, _>`

Comment: `entry` must take the key by value because that API allows you to insert new values into the map.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you use `entry`, you get either a vacant entry, or an occupied entry.  If the entry is vacant and you want to call certain functions like `or_insert`, you need the actual key, not a reference to it, since you will at that point insert into the map.  Note that we don't know that the key supports `Copy` or `Clone`, so we can't take a reference and clone it.

When you use `get`, however, you don't need an actual value to insert.  It's just fine to take a reference, since you can compute `Hash` and `Eq`, which are required to determine if the key is in the map, using only a reference.  This is more efficient if the key is large, and it can avoid a needless allocation.

In addition, `get` also allows you to use anything which implements `Borrow` for the key.  Thus, if your key is a `String`, you can use a `&str` to `get`.  This is great because your key might be owned, but you want to use a `&str` literal, like `"foo"`, to look up in the map.  In this case, no allocation is required at all because the string is hard-coded in the program's code.